# Unable to create test-answer in Sandbox Question

Tags: support

This question [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) states that you require 10 reputation to be able to post an answer.  According to the site header bar, I currently have 101 reputation on the site `(1 + 100 for association bonus)`.

Does the 10 reputation required not include the association bonus?

edit:
My attempt to ask the question was via the API to test that posting answers would work.  I have not tested doing so directly from the website.

Comment: Thank you.  It works now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - there is a reason - spammers.

Comment: @Oded I'm not saying to unprotect all questions, just that the sandbox itself is used to test stuff including from low rep users. If you'll take a look in the revisions, high rep users keep unprotecting it. As for spam, the recent spam attacks focus on a single post and spam via suggested edits, so protecting questions isn't really relevant...

Comment: Well, now you can post even with it being protected. I personally disagree with @Oded decision to leave it Protected but won't fight it any further for now.

Comment: @Oded In all fairness, most of that post is spam, anyways.

Comment: @Sean - you must have a very strange definition of spam.

Comment: @Oded I mean it in the most loving way, of course: [(1)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131825/188148) [(2)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242112/188148) [(3)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71407/188148) [(4)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240581/188148) [(5)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209292/188148).  My point is that it is a testing ground -- most of the answers there are hardly meaningful, so I'm not sure what is being protected.

Comment: @Sean - that's just playing in the sandbox. It isn't trying to sell stuff.

Comment: @Oded Faaaiiir point. :P I forgot about all that *actual* spam we got a few weeks ago -- it was *really* bad on TeX.SX :( I can understand why it's protected now, though :) Random answers would likely go unnoticed given the nature of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the 10 reputation required not include the association bonus?

Yes :)

From the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user):

> Note that one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. The association bonus **does not count**.

Unless you are a mod ;)

Comment: Actually mods can't answer protected questions as well without earning 10 rep first. I think. Let me look...

Comment: @Sha did you find anything on this?